# Can I block svn from committing if the code contains certain keywords?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, source-control

Every once in a while I happen to accidentally commit code containing `console.log` or `debugger;` to my svn trunk. Obviously this is not ideal and I'd like to add checks that'd prevent me from committing code like this in the first place.

**Can I prevent a commit if my code contains certain keywords?**

My svn client of choice is TortoiseSVN. I've been searching on the web for a solution but I mostly found stuff that relates to server-side hooks. My goal is to only run this **client-side**.

Comment: You might be able to set up a pre-commit hook script which greps the file for those values and blocks it. A quick search found this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528302/TortoiseSVN-pre-commit-hook-in-Csharp-Save-yoursel you can set up commit hooks in the TortoiseSVN settings right click settings menu. (Deleted my answer as it was unrelated and I don't have a complete answer)

Comment: You can do it with a wrapper script. Subversion doesn't support client-side hooks.

Comment: @uzsolt Subversion itself does not support client side hooks, but the TortoiseSVN client does.

Comment: Oh, I don't use TortoiseSVN.